# Count posts by language for every tag assigned to a post

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

[image]

Posts have one to many tags. Every post has one language assigned - English or German. I would like to get the count of posts in a specific language per every tag - in other words, I need to know **how many posts in English and German have specific tag assigned**?

The result I have in mind is this:

[image]

`posts_count_en` and `posts_count_de` are aliases. I know the tables should be `JOIN`ed but I have no clue how to `GROUP` the query to get the posts `COUNT`. Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Like you said, a JOIN will probably do what you need. You can definitely get aggregated fields inside joins (COUNT, MAX, MIN, etc.). Then you simply want to group by every column that is NOT an aggregate value (in your case tags.id, tags.name_en, tags.name_de) - I'd suggest w3schools if you want to learn more about COUNT or GROUP http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @Tingo Thanks, the tip about targeting columns that are NOT aggregated is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your question is basically a bunch of joins, aggregation, and some conditions for the different languages:

```
select t.*,
       sum(l.code = 'en') as posts_en,
       sum(l.code = 'de') as posts_de
from posts p join
     languages l
     on p.language_id = l.id join
     post_tags pt
     on pt.post_id = p.id join
     tags t
     on pt.tag_id = t.id
group by t.id;
```

A bigger issue is an inconsistency in your data structure, which I don't fully understand.  The posts have a language id associated with them.  Yet, for the tags, the languages are pivoted across the tag.  Why not have a language id associated with the tags.

This would make the data structure more complex.  You would have tag table with the tag id.  Then a `TagLanguages` table with the mapping to the languages.  I'm not sure if you application needs this flexibility, but it seems strange to access the languages using a join in one case and without a join in the other.

Comment: Different language versions in the `tags` table are there for convenience: in our application, the names of the tags are displayed based on the current app's locale setting. We need to acces tag names a lot, so we did it that way. Not the best DB design probably, though. Thank you!